# Change list of dates from YYYY/MM/DD to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: python, date

I have a simple script that asks for a month and year and then outputs all of the business days in that month, plus the count of business days.

The date output appears as YYYY/MM/DD.

**How do I switch it to DD/MM/YYYY?**

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
import numpy as np
from calendar import monthrange

month = input("Month: ")
year = input("Year: ")

daysInMonth = monthrange(int(year), int(month))[1] # Extract the number of days in the month


sdate = date(int(year), int(month), 1)   # start date
edate = date(int(year), int(month), int(daysInMonth))   # end date

delta = edate - sdate       # as timedelta

numberOfDays = 0

for i in range(delta.days + 1):  # Look through all days in the month
    day = sdate + timedelta(days=i)
    if np.is_busday([day]): # Determine if it's a business day
        print("- " + str(day))
        numberOfDays += 1

print("Working days:" + str(numberOfDays))
```

Comment: Use [`date.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to specify a different output format.  You can also use the same formatting specifiers in format strings, e.g. `print(f'- {day:%d/%m/%Y}')`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation, you will see that for a `date` instance `day`, calling `str(day)` is equivalent to `day.isoformat(' ')`.

For formatting a `date` as a string, there are a couple of solutions:

- `date.ctime()`; this gives `"Fri Aug  5 00:00:00 2022"`
- `date.isoformat(" ")`: `"2022-08-05"`
- `date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`: `"05/08/2022"`

Using `date.strftime()` is the most flexible solution.

In this case, use `day.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 21 to

```
print("- " + day.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```